# Make: Can we Optimize make file targets?

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make

We are supporting 32 bit and 64 bit build in our workflow.For that We have multiple rules in makefiles which are separate for 32-bit and 64-bit. Let me show pair of rules which are same except for the string “32” vs “64” .

Makefile Snippet:-

```
$(TGTDIR32)/logdir/set_user.c: $(CURDIR)/slv/set_user.c
    $(file_transfer)

$(TGTDIR64)/logdir/set_user.c: $(CURDIR)/slv/set_user.c
    $(file_transfer)
```

If you notice, We have targets with same except for the string “32” vs “64”, i want to replace them by single rule/definition. Because we have hundreds of rules like above in our infrastructure code.

Do we have any simplified way in GNUmake to do that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is an appropriate place to use recursive make, at least for the top-level build.

In this situation you could do something like this:

```
TGTDIR64 = ...
TGTDIR32 = ...

.PHONY: all all32 all64 build

all: all32 all64

all32:
        $(MAKE) TGTDIR=$(TGTDIR32) build
all64:
        $(MAKE) TGTDIR=$(TGTDIR64) build

# Things below here should just use TGTDIR

build: $(TGTDIR)/b1 $(TGTDIR)/b2

$(TGTDIR)/logdir/set_user.c: $(CURDIR)/slv/set_user.c
        $(file_transfer)

$(HEADERGEN_NOTSPLIT_H_COPY): $(TGTDIR)/%.h: %.h $(copy_file)
        ...
```

Comment: Mike Kinghan's answer seems to work.. But not sure how i can handle with static pattern rules like : '$(HEADERGEN_NOTSPLIT_H_COPY32): $(TGT32)/%.h: %.h $(copy_file)'

Comment: You cannot use Mike's method with static pattern rules or pattern rules: for those you will still have to write two separate rules.  It will only work with normal explicit rules.  And of course, you're still writing the targets twice even there (although the rest of the rule is combined).

Comment: hI, Unfortunately your answer in above box wont help in our flow.. Is there any other way to implement it whithout recursive make?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of options.  But since you clearly have certain requirements, that you've not provided here, nor described why the existing suggestions that have already been made aren't sufficient, I'm hesitant to keep suggesting more things randomly.  Please state what exactly your requirements are and why these won't work and maybe we can suggest something that will.

Comment: MadScientist, Thing is we have one config.mak where we declare all variables (seperately for 32bit & 64bit ) i.e TGT32 assigned with 32bit path & TGT64 assigned with 64bit path. We are including config.mak file in all of our project makefiles. Which has separate targets referring to 32bit & 64bit paths.. Now we want to optimize our makefiles to have a single target for both 32bit & 64bit.

Comment: MadScientist, Can you please give one sample example make files explaining my above comment. And one important thing regarding our flow is we have three targets (all32,all64,all) that we pass to our make command.. User will pass one target as per there requirement... I am not sure how we can handle this case if we want to build both 32bit and 64bit build at once where 'all' target will do both.. Appreciate your help...

Comment: MadScientist, Additional note for clarity:- In my main question above inside the box i have mentioned two targets which are in GNUmakefile which includes config.mak where TGTDIR32 ,TGTDIR64

Comment: I don't understand why my suggestion above won't work based on your description here.  The basic idea is, write all your rules once using a variable `TGTDIR`.  Then define a target `all32` which recursively invokes make with `TGTDIR=$(TGTDIR32)` and define a target `all64` which recursively invokes make with `TGTDIR=$(TGTDIR64)`.  Then define an `all` rule which depends on `all32` and `all64`.  It seems to do exactly what you want.  Make's parallel job support will allow both sets to be built at the same time even with recursive make.

Comment: If you don't want to use recursive make your only other option is to use `define` to create a macro defining your targets, then use `eval` to invoke the macro once with `TGTDIR32` and then use `eval` to invoke it again with `TGTDIR64`.  This will be pretty messy to be sure.

Comment: Madscientist, Now it makes sense.. I am new to make.. Could you please update your example make above with some more details.. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're asking for WRT "updating the example".  I modified it to use the same terms you are using: `all`, `all32`, and `all64`.  Beyond that I don't know what to say, based on the information you've provided.

Comment: For your initial rules I also don't know why you're writing out a separate rule for every header.  Why don't you just use a pattern rule, like `$(TGTDIR)/logdir/%.c: $(CURDIR)/slv/%.c ; $(file_transfer)` to match all the files (in that directory)?

Answer (score 1):

Targets which have the same prerequisites and recipe can simply be combined, like so:

```
$(TGTDIR32)/logdir/set_user.c $(TGTDIR64)/logdir/set_user.c: $(CURDIR)/slv/set_user.c
    $(file_transfer)
```

or more generally:

```
THESE_TARGETS := $(TGTDIR32)/logdir/set_user.c $(TGTDIR64)/logdir/set_user.c # More...?
...
$(THESE_TARGETS): $(CURDIR)/slv/set_user.c
    $(file_transfer)
```

If Make decides that any member of `$(THESE_TARGETS)` is out-of-date with respect to the prerequisites, then it will run the recipe *for that target*.

This makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: a b c

a: d e
    touch $@

b: d e
    touch $@

c: d e
    touch $@

d:
    touch $@

e:
    touch $@

clean:
    $(RM) a b c d e
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: a b c

a b c: d e
    touch $@

d e:
    touch $@

clean:
    $(RM) a b c d e
```

**Later**

> There are some static pattern rules...

The same applies. This makefile with static pattern rules:

```
.PHONY: default clean

default: a.k b.k

a.k: %.k: %.j
    cp -f $< $@

b.k: %.k: %.j
    cp -f $< $@

a.j:
    touch $@

b.j:
    touch $@


clean:
    $(RM) a.k b.k a.j b.j
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
.PHONY: default clean

JS := a.j b.j
KS := $(JS:.j=.k)

default: $(KS)

$(KS): %.k: %.j
    cp -f $< $@

$(JS):
    touch $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(JS) $(KS)
```

Comment: Mike, $(file_transfer) is defined as follows.                                                              define file_transfer
mkdir -p $(@D)
cp -f $< $@
endef ,                                                                                                                                 'TGTDIR32' & 'TGTDIR64' are different directories.  when we specify 'mkdir -p $(@D)' which target it picks?

Comment: @santosh In the recipe, all [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) -
`$@` etc - will be expanded according to the *actual target* in `$(THESE_TARGETS)` that Make has determined must be made, and its prerequisites.
Nothing special here. It makes no difference whether `$(THESE_TARGETS)` is just one target or a list of targets.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I will test it locally.. Will see if it works.

Comment: Mike, There are some static pattern rules as follows : '$(HEADERGEN_NOTSPLIT_H_COPY32): $(TGT32)/%.h: %.h
                                                                                                   
         $(copy_file)'  How can we handle this case in order to have only one target?

Comment: @santosh Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The two rules are semantically identical, they only use a different way to refer to a "parameterized" target. Why you don't just use one target for this

```
$(TGTDIR)/logdir/set_user.c: $(CURDIR)/slv/set_user.c
    $(file_transfer)
```

and use a properly configured TGTDIR (I suspect this would be something like "xxxx_32" vs "xxxx_64")?

You could achieve this in several ways; one typical would be

```
ifdef choose32
  TGTDIR=xxxx_32
else
  TGTDIR=xxxx_64
endif
```

Comment: One drawback of this proposal is that you cannot build both targets in the same run. There are better ways.

Comment: Yes, I was about mention the same...We cant build both 32 bit & 64 bit builds at once..Users sometimes build there code with both 32 and 64 bit builds at once.. Like we have target all -> to build 32 & 64 bit builds , all32 to build only 32bit build. all64 to build only 64bit build.